# Re-array Excel cells to a new sheet

Tags: python, excel

I would like to just grab data (starting at B29) and copy/paste everything from B29 onwards to a new sheet or make a new csv file. This is the only worksheet I have.
I run into an error:

> KeyError: "None of [Index(['Time', 'A1'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
> for my code.

Excel Sheet screenshot
[image]

```
import pandas as pd

spreadsheet_file = pd.ExcelFile('PlateReader1.xlsx')
worksheets = spreadsheet_file.sheet_names
appended_data = []

for sheet_name in worksheets:
    A1 = 'A1'
    df = pd.read_Excel(spreadsheet_file, sheet_name, header = 30)
    df = df[['Time', A1]]
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your value for `header` is incorrect.

**Here's my dummy file:**

[image]

**Here's the updated code:**

```
import pandas as pd

spreadsheet_file = pd.ExcelFile('PlateReader1.xlsx')
worksheets = spreadsheet_file.sheet_names
appended_data = []

for sheet_name in worksheets:
    A1 = 'A1'
    df = pd.read_Excel(spreadsheet_file, sheet_name, header = 28) # changed 30 to 28
    df = df[['Time', A1]]
    print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
 Time  A1
0     1   1
1     2   2
2     3   3
3     4   4
4     5   5
5     6   6
```